# What is "&" in "scanf("%f", &variableName);" in C programming?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, scanf

I am currently studying C programming language and I was stuck because of "&", below is the sample code.

```
int main()
{
     float degrees, radians;
     printf("Enter an angle in degrees: ");
     scanf("%f", &degrees);
     radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
     printf("%.2f degrees is %.2f radians.\n", degrees, radians);
     return(0);
}
```

Please take a look the bold and italic code. I want to know what is the use of "&". Because when I try to run the code that has no "&" in degrees it does run but when generating the answer it will hang-up.

Appreciate your immediate answer. Thank you!

Comment: One does not simply explain what & means...

Comment: Don't use `return` as if it were a function, it's a keyword. Only wrap in parentheses when returning a complicated expression and just to make it very readable.

Answer (score 4):

The ampersand (&) is the C Address Operator; it returns the memory address of the given variable.

The scanf function reads data from the console, parses it, and stores the result in the *memory address* of the variable provided. The key to understanding the ampersand is that the scanf family of functions actually changes, in memory, the variable provided as an argument. Since we're working with the direct variable in memory and not a copy, we need to pass that variable's memory address -- hence the ampersand (&).

In your sample code the line `scanf("%f", &degrees)` can be read as "Read a float ("%f") value into the memory address of degrees".

You can view the memory address being passed as an argument to scanf by adding the following line of code: `printf("memory address of degrees: %p", &degrees);` before the return statement.

Have a look at the following for more details:
http://see-programming.blogspot.com/2013/10/difference-between-asterisk-and.html
http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%f", &degrees);
```

Here `scanf()` stores value, so it needs a place to store them.
This is done by providing the addresses (in pointers) of
where to store the values. In your case it is `degrees` variable and by using `&degrees` we are providing the address.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator takes the address of the passed parameter and passes a pointer to it into the function, meaning that changing the value of the parameter in the function will also change it's value in the caller function.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of the & as the "address" of the variable in the scanf statement. Essentially, the & is needed for primitive types in scanf statements; You don't see it being used in printf statement.

Take note that when you are using arrays in scanf statement, you will not need to use the & as the array name will provide an implicit &

Answer (score 0):

Ampersand in C means `the value is stored in this (variable)!`